# Convert invalid JSON (having equal sign instead of colon, no quotes etc) to valid JSON

Tags: javascript, android, json, regex, payment-gateway

I am getting data from Cardstream payment gateway android sdk (in native module) to react native but the data is not a valid JSON:

```
'{ __wafRequestID=2021-06-16T08:02:14Z|0e2314f32f|115.186.169.10|gk0GHP1i4V, action=SALE, addressCheckPref=not known,not checked,matched,not matched,partially matched, amount=14, amountRetained=0, avscv2CheckEnabled=Y, caEnabled=Y, cardCVVMandatory=Y, cardExpiryDate=0322, cardFlags=8323072, cardIssuer=UNKNOWN, cardIssuerCountry=United Kingdom, cardIssuerCountryCode=GBR, cardNumberMask=424242******4242, cardNumberValid=Y, cardScheme=Visa, cardSchemeCode=VC, cardType=Visa Credit, cardTypeCode=VC, cftEnabled=N, countryCode=826, currencyCode=826, currencyExponent=2, customerName=fgg, customerReceiptsRequired=Y, cv2CheckPref=not known,not checked,matched,not matched,partially matched, eReceiptsEnabled=N, merchantAlias=100001, merchantID=100001, merchantID2=100001, paymentMethod=card, postcodeCheckPref=not known,not checked,matched,not matched,partially matched, processMerchantID=100001, requestID=60c9b007225c7, requestMerchantID=100001, responseCode=65566, responseMessage=Disallowed cardnumber, responseStatus=2, riskCheckEnabled=Y, riskCheckPref=not known=continue,not checked=continue,approve=continue,decline=decline1,review=authonly,escalate=authonly, riskProcessorID=41, riskProcessorName=Kount, rtsEnabled=Y, scaExemption=lowvalue,trusted, state=finished, surchargeEnabled=Y, surchargeRequired=Y, threeDSCheckPref=authenticated, threeDSEnabled=N, timestamp=2021-06-16 09:02:16, transactionID=112446674, type=1, vcsResponseCode=0, vcsResponseMessage=Success, xref=21061609KX02TQ16YP35TTD}'
```

How to convert it to valid JSON so that I can parse it? I have tried few regex replacements but some values also have colons which is messing it up.

Comment: It's not invalid JSON, it simply is not JSON. You're basically claiming than an apple is an invalid orange because you crave an orange. Contact the payment gateway and ask them how to parse their nonsense.

Comment: Hahha no I am not claiming it, just looking for any workaround to parse it (whatever it is)

Comment: I think the first three words of your title beg to differ; "Convert Invalid JSON". Anyways, the workaround is to contact the payment gateway and ask them how to parse their nonsense.

Comment: A regex is probably not what you want here. You should indeed reach out to the company whose API you're consuming and ask for documentation on how their responses are meant to be parsed. You have no idea if the response you're dealing with now is representative of all future responses or whether some as-yet unseen bit of syntax will completely break your regex. Far better to know ahead, then to fail to correctly handle responses for some window of time in production.

Answer (score 1):

If you wanted to try an parse this with regex then this might work:

```
[{,] (?<key>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)=(?<value>.*?(?=, [a-zA-Z0-9_]+=|\}$))
```

https://regex101.com/r/Fk7NvR/1

Just loop through the matches and access the captured groups named `key` and `value` respectively. The value for `riskCheckPref` seems suspect but I have no clue about their parsing rules.

An alternate idea would be to remove the outer curly braces, trim white space, split on `,`  (comma space), and split again on the first `=`.

Comment: data.replace([{,] (?P<key>[a-zA-Z0-9_]+)=(?P<value>.*?(?=, [a-zA-Z0-9_]+=|\}$)))                         
The regex is throwing error: Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token ','

Comment: @artsnr That was Python. I updated it to JavaScript after seeing your update. Also, why are you using `.replace()`? I presented a solution to extract data. You should use `.match()` per https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Groups_and_Ranges

Comment: @artsnr Also, don't forget that regex literals in JS require a leading and trailing forward slash followed by the global modifier.

Answer (score 0):

I converted response to JSON in **android** and then passed it to react-native instead of passing response to react-native (which gets passed in this invalid format) and then banging my head to convert it to JSON. My bad. Thanks all